# Layering Text Without White Background

Tags: html, css

I am trying to complete the Odin Project's "Sign-Up Form" but I am having trouble with layering the text over the image.

[image]

If I use `position:absolute;` the text does not respect the container's width.

If I use `position:relative;` I get a white background under the text.

I am in dire need of guidance.

Thank you.

```
<div class="container-one">    
    <h1>Sign up now!</h1>
    <img src="1.jpg" alt="">    
</div>

<style>
    img { 
        width: 100%;
        z-index: -1;
    }

    h1 {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
        position: relative;

    }
</style>
```

Comment: Most of us might not know what that `Odin Project's "Sign-Up Form"` is! It might be easier to understand if you could share some photo of how it is showing now and what you were expecting.

Comment: https://cdn.statically.io/gh/TheOdinProject/curriculum/5f37d43908ef92499e95a9b90fc3cc291a95014c/html_css/project-sign-up-form/sign-up-form.png

Comment: Is there a reason for not using the image as a background rather than as a separate element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're almost there with `position: absolute`. The last piece is you need to set `position: relative` to `.container-one` which is the container for both image and text.

```html
<div class="container-one">
  <h1>Sign up now!</h1>
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1612151855475-877969f4a6cc?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8aGQlMjBpbWFnZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&w=1000&q=80" alt="">
</div>

<style>
  .container-one {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
  }
  
  img {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
  }
  
  h1 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
  }
</style>
```

You can check [this doc](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp#:%7E:text=An%20element%20with%20position%3A%20absolute,moves%20along%20with%20page%20scrolling.)

Another solution for your case could be `background-image`

```html
<div class="container-one">
  <h1>Sign up now!</h1>
</div>

<style>
  .container-one {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-image: url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1612151855475-877969f4a6cc?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8MXx8aGQlMjBpbWFnZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&w=1000&q=80');
  }
  
  h1 {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```
.container-one{
  position: relative;  
}

img { 
  width: 100%;  
}

h1 {
  top: 30%;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 55;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Basically you make the `h1` to be absolutely positioned. And sets a higher `z-index` so that it will appear above the image element. And also, set the `container-one` to be relatively positioned so that your absolutely positioned `h1` will use it to calculate it's positioning.

You can control the position using the `top`. And to center align the text, use the `text-align` property.

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s7meg3rp/1/)

Comment: The text is still not respecting the width of the image.

Comment: @bigorangeduck sorry, didn't get you. Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: I am trying to make my text appear exactly as it is in the image. Specifically, the part that says "Odin" for reference. 

My text, when set to position:absolute; spans the length of the page, and not the container that it is within.

Comment: @bigorangeduck just add the `position: relative;` to the `container-one`

Comment: Thank you, Akhilesh, and everyone else for the rest!

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is that you use the image as a background-image for the div containing the text.
you'll have an easy manipulation over everything.